# error while traversing xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, firefox

i am using below code to traverse xml in javascript
i am able to get value using x[i].childNodes[0].text; function in IE but not in firefox.
please tell me what should i use so that it work with all.

```
  function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
function loadxml() {
    var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("xmldata/wfc20100915.xml");


    // documentElement always represents the root node
    x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
    var arr = new Array();
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].childNodes.length > 3) {
            arr[i] = new Array(5);
            arr[i][0] = x[i].childNodes[0].text;
            arr[i][1] = x[i].childNodes[1].text;
            arr[i][2] = x[i].childNodes[2].text;
            arr[i][3] = x[i].childNodes[3].text;
            arr[i][4] = x[i].childNodes[4].text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers (Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) and Internet Explorer interpret child nodes in different ways. In code:

```
<div id="first">
    <div>bla</div>
</div>
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/2Ra3B/ )

Internet Explorer will see only 1 child node of "first".
Modern browsers will see 3 child nodes: 1 element node (div) and 2 text nodes before and after element node (white spaces). Check `nodeType == 3` if you want only text nodes.

Moreover, maybe you should use `data` or `nodeValue` instead of `text` (I don't know if `text` even works, in "classic" browser DOM it doesn't work, but I didn't check it with `responseXML`).

You should also consider using JSON if you want use transfered data only in JavaScript.

PS. You made mistake in code: checking if `childNodes.length > 3` instead of `> 4` or better looking `>= 5`.